# Laravel Form::password is not showing value if it is read only

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

Laravel Form::password is not showing value if it is read only - but working well with Form::text

```
Form::password('password', array('readonly', 'value'=> $item ? $item->password : null, 'class'=>'form-control', 'required' => true))
```

[image]

Comment: Why would you pre-populate a password field?

Comment: i need to populate, the admin wants to view or update the passwords of user, 
users are using an api, and each user have password to access the api @TimLewis

Comment: You should never be able to view passwords... If you're storing them in plaintext, then you have a huge security flaw in your system. The admin should be able to update, but they would simply enter a brand new password, which requires no pre-population.